# Edit File Image Upload using PHP

Tags: php, database, upload

I've been having issues with file upload. After help on this site I managed to upload the files successfully to the db and can pull them back to show the images.Part of my assessment is the fact I need the ability to edit my photo choices (by say choosing a different image and maybe keeping one or two the same) and then the user can submit any changes they may wish to make.So on a separate file called 'edit.php' I have pre-populated all the other data that was entered in the db (this works fine) My code looks like:

```
<label for ="file">Filename:</label>
  <?php echo "<img src='upload/".$_FILES['filename']."' />"; ?>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" >
  <?php echo "<img src='upload/".$_FILES['filename']."' />"; ?>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" >
  <?php echo "<img src='upload/".$_FILES['filename']."' />"; ?>
  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" >
```

PHP:

```
    $name = strtolower($name);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $name);
$extension = end($temp);

if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if($_FILES['file']['size'][$f] < 2000000)
    {
        $uniqid = uniqid();

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], "upload/" . $uniqid  . "." . $extension);


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehiclesimages (vehicleid, filename) VALUES (".$last_id.", '".$uniqid .".".$extension."')");

    }
    else
    {
        echo "File size to big!";   
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Image not supported, please try again!";  
}
```

Any ideas/help or useful sites would be greatly appreciated.As I have been unable to research any info on the subject.

Comment: what is your problem? Where you are struck?

Comment: I was going to ask what you want to achieve?

Comment: WHAT IS $f? YOU DEFINED

Comment: Sorry guys. I have successfully uploaded the pics so when i click on this file i want to give the user the option to either keep the file they originally uploaded or browse for a new one